# Probability of different coloured disks: What's wrong with my approach?

Tags: probability, combinations

> A bag contains 15 coloured discs: 6 blue, 4 red, 3 yellow and 2 green.
> Four discs are chosen at random. What is the probability that they are
> different colours?

My approach: There is a $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}$ that the discs will be removed in a specific order of colours, and there are $4!$ such orders of  blue, red, yellow and green, so the probability that all discs are a different colour is $\frac{4!}{6\times4\times3\times2}=\frac{1}{6}$.

However, my textbook has a different solution: There are $6\times4\times3\times2$ collections of $4$ discs all of different colours, out of  a total of $15\choose 4$ collections of 4 discs. So the probability is $\frac{6\times4\times3\times2}{15\choose4}=\frac{48}{455}$.

I would like to know what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that you get blue, then red, then yellow then green is not as you give it, but $\frac{6}{15} \times \frac{4}{14} \times \frac{3}{13} \times \frac{2}{12}$. This is because the probability that you get blue on your first draw is $\dfrac{\text{number of possible blue discs drawn}}{\text{number of possible discs drawn}}$. But there are now only $14$ discs in the bag, $4$ of them red, so the probability that you get red on your second draw is $\frac{4}{14}$. Now multiply by $4!$, as you say, and you wil get the same answer as your textbook (by a different argument).